# Mysql dump restore doing some funny stuff

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I am using linux platform. I also dump the data into a file and I restore into a server and I ran this command

```
[root@localhost /]# mysqldump -u root -p fms  < /device.sql
```

The funny part it keep running and this dump only consist of table data and I see other table data being run when I run this command where is the other table data comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
mysql -u root -p fms < /device.sql
```

This will import SQL from /device.sql into the fms database

mysqldump only outputs and is not designed to input anything

Doing this

```
mysqldump -u root -p fms
```

will echo the mysqldump all all tables currenly in the fms database

Comment: Sorry rolando I got it was my mistake overlook it.